# git hooks pre-commit issue in Ubuntu Linux

Tags: git

I am trying to run pre-commit command on Ubnut Linux but having trouble to locate file pre-commit.

Running below command
`.git/hooks/pre-commit'

Output
`/bin/sh: 58: .git/hooks/pre-commit: not found`

I checked files in `.git/hooks' direcotry and found below list

Linux `.git/hooks` files

```
-rwxr-x--- 1 User User  478 Jul 31 12:43 applypatch-msg.sample
-rwxr-x--- 1 User User  896 Jul 31 12:43 commit-msg.sample
-rwxr-x--- 1 User User 3079 Jul 31 12:43 fsmonitor-watchman.sample
-rwxr-x--- 1 User User  189 Jul 31 12:43 post-update.sample
-rwxr-x--- 1 User User  424 Jul 31 12:43 pre-applypatch.sample
-rwxr-x--- 1 User User  416 Jul 31 12:43 pre-merge-commit.sample
-rwxr-x--- 1 User User 1492 Jul 31 12:43 prepare-commit-msg.sample
-rwxr-x--- 1 User User 1348 Jul 31 12:43 pre-push.sample
-rwxr-x--- 1 User User 4898 Jul 31 12:43 pre-rebase.sample
-rwxr-x--- 1 User User  544 Jul 31 12:43 pre-receive.sample
-rwxr-x--- 1 User User 3610 Jul 31 12:43 update.sample
```

However, same command is working on my Mac and I compare files in `.git/hooks` folder and clearly can see two files are missing `pre-commit` and `pre-commit.sample`

Mac `.get/hooks`

```
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 User User  staff   478 Jun  9 13:32 applypatch-msg.sample
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 User User  staff   896 Jun  9 13:32 commit-msg.sample
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 User User  staff  4726 Jun  9 13:32 fsmonitor-watchman.sample
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 User User  staff   189 Jun  9 13:32 post-update.sample
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 User User  staff   424 Jun  9 13:32 pre-applypatch.sample
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 User User  staff   354 Jul 21 12:36 pre-commit
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 User User  staff  1643 Jun  9 13:32 pre-commit.sample
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 User User  staff   416 Jun  9 13:32 pre-merge-commit.sample
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 User User  staff  1374 Jun  9 13:32 pre-push.sample
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 User User  staff  4898 Jun  9 13:32 pre-rebase.sample
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 User User  staff   544 Jun  9 13:32 pre-receive.sample
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 User User  staff  1492 Jun  9 13:32 prepare-commit-msg.sample
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 User User  staff  2783 Jun  9 13:32 push-to-checkout.sample
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 User User  staff  3650 Jun  9 13:32 update.sample
```

I tried to re-install it but did not help.

`sudo apt pip install pre-commit`

Comment: What is the script line that raises the error `/bin/sh: 58: .git/hooks/pre-commit: not found`? `.git/hooks/pre-commit` is a relative path. If the current working directory is not the root of the repository, `.git/hooks/pre-commit` is unreachable.

Comment: use `pre-commit uninstall` and the `pre-commit install` to reset the hook.